# Visual Studio cannot find *any* Assembly References after opening Solution on new computer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, assemblies, gac

**TLDR VERSION**:  I've tried everything but VS refuses to look for assembly references in the application directory.  Cannot even set Copy Local = True.. VS just keeps changing it back to false. Halp.

**DETAILED VERSION**:
Here's the scenario: I work in both Visual Studio 2005 (for older support projects, I have no choice), as well as Visual Studio 2010.

I recently purchased a new computer and moved over four (4) of the VS 2005 applications I need to support.  I copied the application directories over, opened the respective web application projects in VS 2005, and pulled down the latest files from source control.

- Two of the projects build fine, see all assembly references in the application (BIN) folder, and life is great.
- Two of the projects will not build, stating that it cannot find the assembly references
- I confirmed that the DLLs for the non-building projects exist in the application (BIN) folders
- These same projects compile fine in two other environments, with the same OS, etc
- For the applications that *will* build, Copy Local = True for each assembly
- For the non-building applicatio, Copy Local = False
- I am unable to change the attributes to Copy Local = True. When I change it to true and move focus off the attribute, it switches back to False. wtf. (so this means VS is not even looking for the assemblies in the application (BIN) folder??)
- For the non-building projects, all of the assembly references show yellow exclamation marks
- I tried adding a Reference Path to the Project's properties, but this did nothing

I am at wit's end, having muddled through this all day long.  I briefly attempted to add the non-building project assemblies to the GAC, but the VS cmd prompt claimed I did not have Admin rights to do so (even though I do).  I would rather have it find the assemblies in the app directory. Halp.

Screenshots of nearly identical solutions below (one works fine, the other can't find references).

[image: Solution 1]

[image: Solution 2]

Comment: I have to set these up every 1-2 years and there's always some snafu. What's weird now is that two of the four solutions work fine with nearly identical structures. :P

Comment: Simply learn about MSBuild syntax, and then open the csproj file in Notepad. You will see how Visual Studio saves the reference information, and it will explain why VS fails to find them on the new machine.

Comment: Any pointers on where to start with MSBuild syntax?  I have already unloaded the project, opened the project file for editing, and compared it to a working project file on the same machine.  The references appeared fairly similar, but there must be some intricacies I am unaware of.

Comment: There are many Microsoft articles (and blog posts around the world) on this topic, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.80%29.aspx. In your case, you should focus on a <ItemGroup> that only contains <Reference> tags. You should see if the <HintPath> tag for each <Reference> points to the valid path on the new machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW.  Just figured this out and I can now move on with my life.

**TLDR Version:** 
Re-installed WebProfileBuilder and all references sorted themselves out!

**Detailed Version:**
As it turns out, the two solutions that would not see Assembly References both relied on the Membership framework (WebProfileBuilder components).  While I did move over the WebProfileBuilder dependencies, I did not *re-install* the WebProfileBuilder installation package.

After re-installing the WebProfileBuilder MSI found [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WebProfileBuilder/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=980) all of the references magically sorted themselves out.  Odd considering most of those references hold little or no relationship to WebProfileBuilder.

I used the MSBuild command line interface to get additional details, which straightened me out.  MSBuild showed no issues with the other assembly references, *ONLY* with WebProfileBuilder.  So thanks for the tip on using MSBuild!  That ultimately helped me get to the root of this issue!

Onward to setting up my VS2010 environment!

Answer (score 0):

*usually* when you see this its because a relative path reference to the library is not the same as it was on the other system. 
Is the project at the *exact* same location? Are the references at the *exact* same location?
Also ensure the current user you are running as has permissions to the folder with the reference library in it.

Remove the references and re-add them. You can try for completeness just remove the ajaxcontroltookit, close the solution and open it and then add the reference.

Comment: The first thing I tried was removing and re-adding the references, to no avail. As mentioned, Local Copy = False for all references. If I change it to True, the IDE will change it back to False. For the two Solutions that wok, Local Copy = True.  I also tried re-copying the physical DLLs to the folder, but none of that matters presumably because Visual Studio refuses to allow Local Copy = True.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that you installed all the service packs for visual studio and .NET?  Did you also install any hotfixes, Web Application Project update, VS 2005 SP1 Update for Vista (needed for Windows 7 as well), etc..?

Comment: Yes. Before even loading these applications I let Windows Update download and install all relevant updates, service packs, and hotfixes (with restarts).

Comment: @user303644 - I'm talking about Visual Studio updates, which is not the same as Windows updates.  Sometimes Windows Update will include a patch or service pack for Visual studio, but not all updates are distributed that way.

Comment: Yes, it is up to date.  Just confirmed in Visual Studio > Help > Check for Updates.

Comment: @user303644 - that doesn't work either.  The check for updates never returns anything.